# How to get Notepad++ v7.8.2 to automatically indent tab(s) instead of space(s)

Tags: notepad++

I am with Notepad++ v7.8.2 and using it to edit Python files.

When editing an existing Python file and hitting the Enter key, I found the new line was auto-indent to align with the previous line but with multiple spaces instead of tabs. As the file is tab-indent, I have had to manually replace the spaces with tabs to able to run the file.

I have checked the following settings:

```
Preference -> MISC -> Auto-indent is ON.
```

Is there any other setting I need to configure to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Settings > Preferences. From the list on the left, choose Language. In the Language menu, select Python. The tab settings for Python are on the right.

Here is a screenshot of the default values (using 4 spaces), uncheck "Replace by space" to use tabs.

[image]

Comment: I'm using 7.8.7 (64-bit) and this procedure doesn't work for configuring auto-indent.

Comment: Try upgrading to 7.8.9 (64-bit) - it works. Also, make sure that you have selected python in Tab Settings section - you may have forgotten to do so. I did that and it did not work until I fixed that mistake.